# Should real honey be reserved for medical purposes for the wellbeing of the world's bees?

Tags: veganism, health, substitutes, medicine, honey

Honey has been used for medicinal purposes for centuries, and recent studies have shown that it can be effective in treating a variety of ailments. Honey is a natural antibacterial agent, and it has been shown to be effective in treating wounds and preventing infections. In addition, honey has powerful anti-inflammatory properties, making it an effective treatment for sore throats and other inflammatory conditions. The medicinal properties of honey are believed to be due to the presence of enzymes and other compounds that are unique to honey bees. As a result, many people believe that real honey should be reserved for medical purposes in order to protect the world's bee population. While there are synthetic alternatives to honey, they lack the medicinal properties of real honey, making them less effective treatments for many conditions.

In consideration of our hardworking bee friends, should real honey be reserved for medical use?

Comment: The trouble with this question is that you're really just soliciting opinions. Generally vegans are going to say leave the bees alone and vegetarians may well say that the bees are still alive so that's OK. The only thing an answer could really cover would be vegan alternatives to the medicinal effects of honey.